# Sort while reading into a vector

Tags: c++, vector, int

I need to read in a list of 10,000 integers, and place them in a vector in ascending order. Note that I am not reading *then* sorting, I am sorting *while* reading.

I am doing this as a learning exercise. I realise that sorting while reading is O(n^2), while reading then sorting could be O(n + (n log(n)) with a quick sort or similar.

I have done this in a C Array, but I'm having troubles doing this with a vector. Any advice on how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** C array code:

To fully explain, I have two classes. ArrayIntStorage, and VectorIntStorage.

The whole point is that this is a learning exercise.

Each of these classes has a _data member variable, one is an int[], and one is a vector.
Each class has a read and write method, this is the read method for the ArrayIntStorage

```
void ArrayIntStorage::read(istream &sin)
{
string x;
sin >> x >> _numberOfInts;

_data = new int[_numberOfInts];

if(_sortRead)
{
    int i, j, index;
    sin >> _data[0];

    for(i = 1; i < _numberOfInts; i++)
    {
        sin >> index;

        j = i;
        while((j > 0) && (_data[j-1] > index))
        {
            _data[j] = _data[j - 1];
            --j;

        }
        _data[j] = index;
    }
}
else
{
    for(int i = 0; i < _numberOfInts; ++i)
    {
        sin >> _data[i];
    }
}   
}
```

Comment: What is your array code?

Comment: "Array code" can mean a million things, Do you mean my sort method for my C Array, my Array definition..?

Comment: You say "I have done this in a C array"...

Comment: Why is it exactly that you have problem with vectors but not with arrays?

Comment: int i, j, index;
  sin >> _data[0];

  for(i = 1; i < _numberOfInts; i++)
  {
   sin >> index;

   j = i;
   while((j > 0) && (_data[j-1] > index))
   {
    _data[j] = _data[j - 1];
    --j;

   }
   _data[j] = index;
  }

Sorry about formatting I am fairly new to stack overflow.
Note that "sin" is an ifstream that I am passing into this "read" method.

Comment: @cswilby: You should edit your question, and add this code to it, so that people know what the starting point is...

Comment: Because in a C Array, I can declare a new int[10000] and have 10,000 "slots" available to me, but in a vector I can only push_back.

Comment: @cswilby: with vector you can do [much much more](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) than just push_back or with new int[10000].

Comment: have a look at vector::resize also are you sure you are using the right container at all, what other operations are you doing on it?

Comment: Note: `O(n + (n log(n))`  is always written as `O(N.log(N))` or `O(N.ln(N))` (I have forgotten which is actually correct log/ln but I have seen it both ways so many times that I auto convert in my head now. SOmbody will pipe up with the correct answer). The `n +` part is dropped as insignificant as N increases. Note 2: ln(X) is a base 2 log while log(X) is a base 10 log.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

example time:

```
std::vector<int> target;

// reading
std::ifstream file("integers.txt");
int number; 
while (file >> number) 
{
  target.insert(std::lower_bound(target.begin(), target.end(), number), number);
}
```

Comment: @Karl: In general, `std::insert` will be *O(n)*, which makes the whole thing *O(n^2)*.

Comment: @Oli Okay, but we have to do this `insert()` call, don't we?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth Yep, but that's what the questioner asked for. He said he realized it would be O(n^2).

Comment: That should be target.insert, not std::insert. Also, this code assumes there is a newline between each number, and it assumes there is *not* a newline at the end of the file. It would be better to do the while test on the result of getline, instead of a separate test for eof. Why not something like ` int number;
 while (file >> number) {
  target.insert(std::lower_bound(target.begin(), target.end(), number), number);
 }
`

Comment: Adapted this to fit into my class, specifically the insert method was most helpful! Thanks Karl von Moor.

Comment: @cswilby Nice to hear :D @Daniel Concerning the `insert()` thing – I already had edited the answer. And concerning the EOF thing – I'll go and edit :D

Comment: **This solution is still O(N^2)**. That's goignt to get very expensive (especially if the data is reverse sorted). Copy all the members of the array around on each insert is not a good idea. Better to build a sorted container (then when complete copy into a vector). The complexity is big because because the insert has a complexity of O(N) (Which is greater than the O(Ln(N)) of finding the insertion point). Doing this N times we get O(N^2).

Answer (score 1):

I haven'tcompiled it but using a priority queue is also possible

```
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

    priority_queue<int> pq;
    // reading
    std::ifstream file("integers.txt");
    string line;
    while (getline(file, line))
    {
          int number = boost::lexical_cast<int>(line);

        pq.push (number);
    }
```

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974470/efficiency-of-the-stl-priority-queue) push() is O(log(N)) and pop is O(2*log(N))

Comment: I will take a look at priority_queues as well once I have finished learning vectors, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a `multiset` to do the sorting for me:

```
void VectorIntStorage::read(istream &sin) {
    multiset<int> ms;
    copy(istream_iterator<int>(sin), istream_iterator<int>(),
        inserter(ms, ms.end()));
    vector<int>(ms.begin(), ms.end()).swap(_data); 
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution.: O(N.ln(N))