# Get (next) Max object from a vector

Tags: c++, performance, sorting, vector, max

OK, so here's my issue :

- I'm having a class (let's call that `MyClass`), with several variables (one of which is `score`)
- I'm also having a vector of `MyClass` objects (e.g. `vector<MyClass> MyObjects;`)

Now, given that I tried sorting the array (with `sort(MyObjects.begin(),MyObjects.end(),MyClassCompare());`) and noticed a considerable drop in performance (and also that some of the elements of the vector may not be needed at all in the end), I'm trying to :

- Pick the (current) max element (the one with the maximum `score` value)
- Remove that from the vector
- Pick next max element
- And so on...

Is there any way to achieve that using built-in functions/libraries, in C++?
Any ideas?

---

**HINT :** Speed and performance are *crucial*.

Comment: Is there a reason they can't be inserted in sorted order?

Comment: @sixlettervariables Yep, because of the way the vector's elements are being generated, sorting them beforehand (a.k.a. inserting them in sorted order) would be an absolute performance killer.

Comment: Have you tried [std::make_heap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap)?

Comment: @StoryTeller Haven't actually tried it; but won't it suffer the same speed drop as vector sorting (or even worse)?

Comment: Well, the documentation specifies the run time is at most `3*len(range)`. If you don't need all the elements, using this method along with std::pop_heap may be cheaper performance-wise. I can't guarantee.

Comment: What about [std::partial_sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort)?

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon: well you either incur performance sorting or you incur performance searching. Sorting would occur N times (where N is the number of items you're creating) and searching would occur M times, where M is the number of times you need to do your pick/remove. You'll have to incur performance penalties somewhere, so either do it upfront at insertion or do it at search time (which you've found is "considerable").

Answer (score 1):

If you require access to the maximum valued element of a collection, you will have to incur some performance hit either (a) upfront at insertion time, or (b) during searching time. You've noted that (b) is expensive, probably due to the method you chose, and are asking how you can make this quicker.

Out of the box you have [`priority_queue`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974470/efficiency-of-the-stl-priority-queue) which provides probably exactly what you are looking for. I would imagine the performance would be better than your current code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are "collecting" data that you are later going to select things in some order (biggest, smallest, etc), you will have a few choices:

1. sorting as you go.
2. sorting when you have collected all the data.
3. have poor performance when searching for your data.
4. create TWO sets of data, where one is sorted, with some sort of index to your unsorted data items.

In your case, you are talking of removing some data as from the collection as well. Is it required that you actually remove the data, or that you simply keep track of what you "no longer need"? If the latter, perhaps option four above is a good choice - you simply remove it from the sorted table. Since this is much smaller than the list of items itself [presumably "MyClass" is bigger than two integers].