# Why the complexity of pop_heap is O(2 * log(N))?

Tags: stl, heap, priority-queue, asymptotic-complexity

I saw in a several places that in priority_queue, the complexity of pop_heap is O(2 * log(N)), is that true? If yes, where that 2 come from? After removing first element it just needs to reconstruct heap, which would take O(log(N)).

Comment: The 2 is irrelevant. O(2 lg(N)) is the same as O(lg(n)).

Comment: I know, I want to know where 2 comes from.

Comment: Who knows? Putting a constant inside doesn't mean *anything*, because O(lg(n)) may already hide some other constant. Multiply that constant by 2, you still have some arbitrary constant that can be overlooked by using O-notation. You'd have to ask whoever wrote that pop_heap is O(2*log(n)) what they meant by that.

Comment: I know that 2 doesn't matter in overall complexity. Please see here the first answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974470/efficiency-of-the-stl-priority-queue

Comment: If it's wrong, why it has 17 upvotes? )

Comment: They are talking about a *particular* implementation, and notice the quote from the C++ standard doesn't talk about O(lg(n)) complexity; it specifically mentions the number of comparisons made. *That's* the difference.

Comment: Yes you are right, but still I don't understand, why according to standard pop_heap may use 2logN comparisons, whereas push_heap only logN

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> why according to standard pop_heap may use 2logN comparisons, whereas push_heap only logN

To start with, remember heap has a structure of a binary tree, it means each node has at most **two** children (and obviously at most **one** parent).

How `pop_heap` works:

- Take top element. (O(1))
- Take last element and place it on the top. (O(1))
- Update heap using **top -> bottom** logic. You start from the top element and compare it with its **two children**. Switch current element with one of its children and proceed to the next level, or stop if current element is already in correct place (condition of the heap holds)

How `push_heap` works:

- Place element as the last element (leaf of the tree). (O(1))
- Update heap using **bottom -> top** logic. You start with element you just added, and compare it with its **parent**. Switch current element with its parent if necessary and proceed, or stop if condition of the heap holds already.

So, the main difference between two above operations is the logic of heap update (reconstruct). `pop_heap` uses **top to bottom** logic, and `push_heap` uses **bottom to top** logic. Both of them are of O(logN) complexity, since the whole structure is a binary tree. But `pop_heap` requires more comparisons because each time we need to compare current element with both **2 children**. In the same time, during `push_heap` we need to compare current element only with its **1 (and only) parent**.