# What type of heap is used and time complexity of std::priority_queue in c++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, priority-queue, dijkstra

#### What do I want to know

I want to ask about following two question.

- What type of heap is used in std::priority_queue in C++?
- What is the time complexity of `top(), pop(), push()` operation for std::priority_queue in C++?

I checked on the Internet, but I couldn't find the answer.
Please tell me the answer. If you don't know all version in C++, please tell me this answer for GCC C++11 or C++14.

#### Why do I need

I want to implement [Dijkstra's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) for shortest-path problem.

Let the `number of vertex = |V|, number of edge = |E|` in the graph.
The time complexity is `O(|E| log |V|)` with using [Binary Heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap).
but the time complexity is `O(|E| + |V| log |V|)` with using [Fibonacci Heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap).

As you can see, the time is very different if the graph is dense.
Actually, there's `O(|V|^2)` algorithm without using heaps, so I also want to know whether I have to implementate it.

#### My Implementation

Here's my implementation of priority queue with [Binary Heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap).
`insert(x)` is equal to `push(x)`, and `extract()` is equal to `top() --> pop()`.
But std::priority_queue is far more faster than my implementation.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
template<class T> class PriorityQueue {
private:
    size_t size_; vector<T> heap;
public:
    PriorityQueue() : size_(1), heap(vector<T>(1, 0)) {};
    PriorityQueue(PriorityQueue& que) : size_(que.size_), heap(que.heap) {};
    size_t size() { return size_ - 1; }
    inline void insert(int x) {
        unsigned ptr = size_++; heap.push_back(x);
        while (ptr > 1) {
            if (heap[ptr >> 1] < heap[ptr]) swap(heap[ptr], heap[ptr >> 1]);
            ptr >>= 1;
        }
    }
    inline int extract() {
        int ret = heap[1]; unsigned ptr = 1;
        while ((ptr << 1) + 1 < size_) {
            ptr <<= 1;
            if (heap[ptr] > heap[ptr + 1]) swap(heap[ptr >> 1], heap[ptr]);
            else swap(heap[ptr + 1], heap[ptr >> 1]), ptr++;
        }
        heap[ptr] = heap[--size_], heap[size_] = 0;
        while (ptr > 1) {
            if (heap[ptr >> 1] < heap[ptr]) swap(heap[ptr], heap[ptr >> 1]);
            ptr >>= 1;
        }
        heap.pop_back();
        return ret;
    }
};
```

EDIT: This is not duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974470/efficiency-of-the-stl-priority-queue). There's only about time complexity. I also want to know what type of heap is used. Please tell me simply.

Comment: top and pop have a constant complexity, and push has a logarithmic complexity. The C++ standard does not specify what **type** of a heap should be used. It just specifies the target complexities which the implementation must comply with.

Comment: @ilim There's no information for what type of heap (ex. binary heap / fibonacci heap), so it is not duplicate.

Comment: @square1001 *But std::priority_queue is far more faster than my implementation.*  -- The source is available by just looking at the header file.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan pop is not constant

Comment: What is the difference (in time complexity of operations) between Binary and Fibonacci heaps?  If you can answer that, you can see what the C++ standard requires (it may allow either), if you can't answer that - why do you care?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer by @IvayloStrandjev already mentions that C++ standard doesn't require a specific implementation, rather it requires a time complexity. So this is implementation dependent. Since you have mentioned GCC in the question, I have found [this documentation of GCC about the implementation of priority queue](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/ext/pb_ds/pq_design.html).

Basically it says that multiple implementations are presents:

- Paring Heap
- Binary Heap
- Binomial Heap
- RC Binomial Heap
- Thin Heap

And the one used can be be configured through a tag parameter. The default tag is for **pairing heap**. So I guess that's the one being used by default in GCC.

**Edit**: As pointed by @MartinBonner in comment, the link is for `__gnu_pbds::priority_queue` instead of `std::priority_queue`. I missed that before.

`std::priority_queue` uses `make_heap` function which eventually uses [__push_heap method from bits/stl_heap.h](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/e11be3ea01eaf8acd8cd86d3f9c427621b64e6b4/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_heap.h#L121-L136). A quick glance at the code looks like an implementation of **Binary Heap**.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you. How do you provide a tag parameter?

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev honestly, I don't know. Still trying to figure it out.

Comment: it is a template parameter when constructing the heap as it seems from the documentation.

Comment: Yes. What I'm trying to understand is whether it is fixed or we have the option to change that as c++ application developer (as oppose to compiler developer).

Comment: when you construct the heap you can pass this template argument to choose between the built-in implementations that you've mentioned. If you need another implementation you will have to do more work

Comment: That appears to be the documention of `__gnu_pbds::priority_queue `, not `std::priority_queue`.  Of course the OP can always use the former if he chooses.

Comment: You (can) specify the tag parameter when you instantiate the template:  `__gnu_pbds::priority_queue<int, std::less<int>, __gnu_pbds::binary_heap_tag> my_heap;`

Answer (score 4):

The standard does not specify the concrete implementation of the heap used but rather specifies the complexity of its operations and the memory complexity of the container. The complexities of the operations are as follows:

- top - O(1)
- pop - O(log(n))
- push - O(log(n))
- memory complexity - O(n)

Note that both the Fibonacci and th binary heap comply with these requirements. However from what I've seen usually the implementation is [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap).

One more important remark - Fibonacci heap does have a better asympthotic complexity but its constant factor is larger, so you need a relatively big graph to make it worth using a Fibonacci heap instead of Binary Heap. This a common mistake - better asympthotic complexity does not mean the algorithm outperforms alternatives for **any** input.

Comment: Looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap#Summary_of_running_times, it appears that the standard requirement for push means that either binary or Fibonacci heaps are legal.

Comment: @MartinBonner in what way does my answer state something else?

Comment: I never meant to imply that your answer did state anything else (but I can see why you might have thought I did).  I was just making it explicit (having done the research, and not seen the statement anywhere else here).  Possibly prefixing my comment with "Further to that, ..." would have helped set the tone better.

Comment: @MartinBonner I will update my answer to make this statement explicit. Thank you.

Comment: The current C++17 draft has tightened requirements for heaps [alg.heap.operations]. For a range [a, b) to be a heap, it is now required that comp(a[(i-1)/2], a[i]) is false (whereas before it was merely required that *a was maximal). If I'm not mistaken, this requires the layout to be that of a binary max-heap. Even before, the push_heap etc., operations operate on ranges, and I don't know how a Fibonacci heap could be done in this setting.