# Why does a priority queue require front(), pop_back() from the underlying container instead of back(), pop_back()?

Tags: c++

From *C++ Primer* and also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue, I know:

> A priority_queue requires random access
>   in addition to the front, push_back, and pop_back operations;

I also read this [blog post](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/03/20/heaps-and-priority-queues-in-c-part-3-queues-and-priority-queues/) from Google and know:

> - push: add a new element to the queue,
> - pop: remove the largest element of the queue,
> - top: access the largest element of the queue.

`push` should be implemented by `push_back`, no problem.
And `pop` and `top` seem to operate on the same element. One is to access it, the other removes it. So I think these two operations should be implemented by `pop_front()` and `front()` or `pop_back()` and `back()`.

So I am confused, why are the requirements `front()` and `pop_back()`?

Let's for example assume the underlying container is a `vector` and with some int elements let's say `1,2,3,4,5,6`. How does the adaptor interface "`pop()`, `top()`" work with the underlying "`front()`, `pop_back()`"?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I just can't understand the connection between the interface of priority queue and the minimal operation (of underlying container) requirements. I mean, why the least needed are `push_back`, `pop_back` and `front`. (`push_back` is easy to understand of course)

Comment: `pop` is used to remove the `top` element. So I think the underlying operation should also target the same element, right? let's say a `vector`, `pop_back()` and `front()`, does not  target the same element.

Comment: I think this is because the priority queue implementation happens through a heap. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974470/efficiency-of-the-stl-priority-queue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although `pop()` on a `priority_queue` is ultimately removing the top element, it must maintain the invariant, which would not happen if all the elements simply shifted over. Thus, it works by swapping the top value from `front()` to `back()` and `pop_back()`ing that, then swapping the displaced value with one of its children until the invariant is restored.

Likewise, `push()` calls `push_back()` and then performs a series of swaps, albeit in the other direction.

Note: since C++ uses a max-heap (contrary to common convention), the invariant is that any element must be *larger* than both of its children (if they exist). Since most useful problems involve a min-heap, you almost always have to specify `std::greater<>` as the `Compare` template argument.

Comment: Sorry I know little about heap (ಥ_ಥ). So as far as I can understand, you are saying that:
E.g. I have `1,2,3` stored in a p-queue(using `vector`). After some sorting, it internally looks like [3][2][1]. When I call `pop`, it turns to be [1][2][3](swapping the top value to back) and then pop out [3], is that right?

Comment: As commonly impl., the order after insertion of `1, 2, 3` would be `3, 1, 2`. That is because after insertion of `2`, the invariant is restored by moving `2` up (I call that "trickle up" in analogy to the "trickle down" described below): `2, 1`. Then, you insert `3` and let that trickle up, so `2, 1` → `2, 1, 3` → `3, 1, 2` (swapping `2` and `3`). On removal, as @o11c said, you swap `front()` and `back()`, do `pop_back()` and then let the new `front()`, "trickle down", so `3, 1, 2` → `2, 1, 3` → `2, 1` (done, no need for `2` to trickle down as it's already > than its (only) child).

Comment: @Rick By the way, you might want to look at the descriptions of [`push_heap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/push_heap) and [`pop_heap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/pop_heap). The pq's `push()` can be implemented as `c.push_back()` followed by `push_heap()`. The pq's `pop()` can be implemented as `pop_heap()` followed by `pop_back()`. There is also `make_heap()` which could be useful when creating a pq from an iterator range (or `initializer_list`, if there were such a constructor) – first create the container by copying from the range, then `make_heap()`.

Comment: @ArneVogel Your detailed explanation is very helpful. I've read something about heap. Combining the answer and your comments now I have a vague understanding about it. Thanks :D.