# time complexity of priority_queue in C++

Tags: c++, time-complexity

I have been trying to figure out the time complexity of a `priority_queue`.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974470/efficiency-of-the-stl-priority-queue) post here states that the complexity of this container depends on the underlying container.
My question is for a `priority_queue` declared as such

```
    using mypair = std::pair<int, int>;
    std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, mypair>, std::vector<std::pair<int, mypair>>, std::greater<std::pair<int, mypair>>> heap;
```

What would the time complexity be for `push` and `pop` will it be `O(log(n))`

Comment: The compute time will depend on the underlying container.  The time complexity (that is, the O() notation), does not.  Lookup is O(N), insert and delete is O(N log N).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heap insertion and extraction have the worst case complexity relative to the height of the tree, thus O(log N), plus the complexity of the underlying data structure.

In case of a `vector`, `push_back` has an amortized complexity O(1), and `pop_back` O(1).

Therefore it can be said that the total time complexity of `push` and `pop` of a `priority_queue` backed by a `vector` is O(log N).